# Convert('yymmdd' as datetime) is not working in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this function in one of the SP it's working in one server but same conversion thouing error in other server .

Example:

```
Convert(datetime,'210319')
```

Error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
> in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Is that 1921 or 2021? How do *you* know?

Comment: And what versions?

Comment: Perhaps a visit to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), paying close attention to the available [style codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), would answer your question.

Comment: Show us examples of the working and failing commands.  Otherwise the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Why are you using SQL Server 2008 still as well? It's been  completely unsupported for 18~ months now. But what you have works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d34bb08c335ace021227f18198255619)

Answer (score 2):

You need a four-digit year.  How about adding one in?

```
Convert(datetime, '20' + '210319')
```